# How to access directly the "CUDA Memory" address from another parallel kernel?

Tags: parallelization, cudalink

I work with CUDALink and have some small successes.
I use direct calculation on GPU without using CPU (only for sanding commands for CUDA function). Until now I have stored on the hard drive with another kernel the data while GPU calculation (a the same time).

My question: How can I access directly the memory address from other kernel?
How can I declarete the memory adress in secound Kernel.

Kernel 1 => CUDA calculation
Kernel 2 => Export table on HDD

**e.g. on two kernels I do in this way "schematically" (I know, it is a bad way):**

```
ParallelEvaluate[

If[$KernelID==1,CUDAmem = CUDAMemoryAllocate [_Integer, {1000000}]];

];

CUDAmemMatematica=ParallelEvaluate[

If[$KernelID==1,CudaMemoryGet[CUDAmem]]

][[1]];

DistributeDefinitions[CUDAmemMatematica];

ParallelEvaluate [

If[$KernelID==1, Here same calculation on CUDAmem with CUDAFunctions];

,

Export["CUDAmem.dat",CUDAmemMatematica,"TABLE"];

];
```

**I woud like to do this in this way "schematically", but dont know how:**

```
ParallelEvaluate[

If[$KernelID==1,CUDAmem=CUDAMemoryAllocate[_Integer,{1000000}]];

];

ParallelEvaluate[

If[$KernelID==2,CUDAmemMatematica=CudaMemoryGet[CUDAmem]];

];

ParallelEvaluate[

If[$KernelID==1,Here same calculation on CUDAmem with CUDAFunctions;

,

Export["CUDAmem.dat",CUDAmemMatematica,"TABLE"];

]];
```

Thanks for Your ideas

Corpec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not very familiar with CUDA, [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3300605/695132) suggests that this is not possible.  Quoting the relevant parts:

> **Q:** Is it possible to have two or more linux host processes that can access the same device memory? -- [Mark Borgerding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3343/mark-borgerding)
>
> **A:** My understanding of the CUDA APIs is that this cannot be done. The device pointers are relative to a given CUDA context, and there's no way to share those between processes. -- [Edric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88076/edric)

Note that Mathematica's subkernels are separate processes.